# Открыть порты к IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, iis

Не могу понять почему нет доступа к сайту IIS, проброску портов сделал в роутере но толку нет, (при проверки через сайт в интернет везде пишет что порты закрыты) в чем может быть проблема.

1.Сайты проверки (**2ip.ru,PortScaner.ru**)

```
   Тип узла. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Гибридный    IP-маршрутизация
включена . . . . : Нет    WINS-прокси включен . . . . . . . : Нет   
Порядок просмотра суффиксов DNS . : Home

Адаптер Ethernet Ethernet:

   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . : Home    Описание. . . . . . . .
. . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller    Физический адрес. .
. . . . . . . : E0-D5-5E-57-F7-79    DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . .
: Да    Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да    Локальный IPv6-адрес
канала . . . : fe80::a933:49d1:56eb:e1cf%19(Основной)    IPv4-адрес. .
. . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.18(Основной)    Маска подсети . . . .
. . . . . . : 255.255.255.0    Аренда получена. . . . . . . . . . : 30
января 2020 г. 8:10:53    Срок аренды истекает. . . . . . . . . . : 31
января 2020 г. 10:38:36    Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . :
192.168.1.1    DHCP-сервер. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1    IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 115397982    DUID клиента DHCPv6 . . .
. . . . : 00-01-00-01-23-84-A4-2F-E0-D5-5E-57-F7-79    DNS-серверы. .
. . . . . . . . . : 84.42.48.10
                                       77.88.8.1
                                       77.88.8.8
                                       213.158.0.6
                                       8.8.8.8    NetBios через TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Включен

Адаптер Ethernet Ethernet 3:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.   
DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :    Описание. . . . . . . . . . . .
. : Kaspersky Security Data Escort Adapter    Физический адрес. . . .
. . . . . : 00-FF-E4-F4-05-51    DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . :
Да    Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да

Адаптер Ethernet Ethernet 4:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.   
DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :    Описание. . . . . . . . . . . .
. : Kaspersky Security Data Escort Adapter #2    Физический адрес. . .
. . . . . . : 00-FF-B0-3F-67-30    DHCP включен. . . . . . . . . . . :
Да    Автонастройка включена. . . . . . : Да
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не хватает `ipconfig /all` и методы проверки портов =)

Comment: В NAT провайдера, например. Сравни свой ip на роутере с тем, который видишь на myip.

Comment: Да вы были правы с IP не учел эту особенность, но проблема не решилась, дополнительно проверил работу с локальной сети и мне постоянно вылетает ошибка Not Found 404